# Continuous scrolling with mouse thumb buttons?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

In windows I used X-Mouse Button Control to accomplish this, but I can't find a method of doing It in linux.

My main mouse is a logitech m510 which has two thumb buttons on the side, which are buttons 8 and 9.

the closest i've gotten is by using xbindkeys and xte.

~/.xbindkeysrc:

```
#scroll-up-attempt
"xte 'key Up'"
    b:9 + Release

#scroll-down-attempt
"xte 'key Down'"
    b:8 + Release
```

But I want continuous scrolling when I press the button, not just one key movement when I press and release the button... Help?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same thing... This is the closest i've come up with, but i have yet to get it to actually repeat! I suspect there's something wrong with the shell script. My .xbindkeysrc: `" while { xinput --query-state 9 | grep -q "12\]=down"; }; do xte 'mousedown 4' 'sleep 1' 'mouseup 4' ; done "
b:12`

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the same thing (see comment). This does work, though:
.xbindkeysrc:

```
" ~/src/but_10.sh "
b:10
```

and but_10.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
xte 'key Up'
sleep 0.3
while [ $(xinput --query-state 9 | grep -e "button\[10\]=down") ]
do
xte 'key Up'
sleep 0.05
done
```

No idea why this works, while `xte 'mouseclick 4'` doesn't. I'd REALLY like to get it to work that way.

Comment: @lestyn ap Mwg are you still looking for a way to achieve mouseclick 4/5?

Answer (score 0):

@mohkamfer Yes, if you have found a way to make that work. I'm still using the workaround i listed, using 'key Up' and 'key Down'. I would prefer to emulate the scroll wheel.